# debug assertion failed! expression list iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assert, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working on an assignment where I implement a Dictionary (ADT) in C++. I initially wrote the program in Xcode and everything seemed to work fine. However I recently found out that the grader uses Visual Studio 2010 so I tried to make sure my code would work ins VS2010 as well....

The problem I'm running into now is in my `remove()` function for the hash table. Basically, I am using a vector of lists and iterating through lists to delete a collision entry. However now when I try to test this `remove()` function I get the following error: `debug assertion failed! expression list iterators incompatible`. I tried looking through the  Visual C++ documentation on asserts and everything looks like it should work.... is there something I'm overlooking?

Here's my code:

```
///**DELETE***////  
void remove(string key) {
    size_t index = hashString(key);
    list<Entry>& entry = table.at(index);
        for(typename list<Entry>::iterator it = entry.begin();
            it != entry.end();
            /**/)
        {
            if (it->data == key) {
                table[index].erase(it);
            } else
                it++;
        }
    //entry not found
    cout << "Error: Cannot Delete... No Such Entry"<< endl;
}
```

Comment: On what line does the assert happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's suspicious that you're ignoring the return value of `erase`. Does it work if you change the line containing the `erase` call to this?

```
it = table[index].erase(it);
```

Or indeed:

```
it = entry.erase(it);
```

See the documentation of `list::erase` here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase